# Magento 2.2.6 : How to solve this error " Validate class not found from basename 'Magento\Framework\Validator\EmailAddress' "

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.2.6

How to solve this error ?

> "Validate class not found from basename 'Magento\Framework\Validator\EmailAddress'"

Comment: are on Plesk hosting ?

Comment: Did you tried this one ? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/296419/how-to-fix-validate-class-not-found-from-basename-magento/296421#296421

Comment: @Pawan yes I am using Plesk Hosting

Comment: please check solution https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10821#issuecomment-334525946