# Magento 2 Klarna Checkout Validate class not found from basename 'NotEmpty'

Tags: magento2, checkout, validation, klarna, klarnacheckout

I have installed magento2 klarna checkout in my system but getting below error.

[image]

any one have idea how i can solve this ?

Comment: check it and follow step https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/296419/how-to-fix-validate-class-not-found-from-basename-magento

Comment: i already refer same thing also restart  php after this than also getting same error

Comment: i will check it and update you ASAP.